# pygraphviz / grapviz has a non-deterministic output, so how to force the order of the nodes?

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

Running this code:

```
import pygraphviz as PG
tree = PG.AGraph(directed=True, strict=False)

tree.add_node(1)
tree.add_node(2)
tree.add_node(3)
tree.add_node(4)
tree.add_node(5)

tree.add_edge(1, 2)
tree.add_edge(1, 3)
tree.add_edge(4, 4)
tree.add_edge(1, 5)

print str(tree)
```

has the following output:

```
digraph {
        1 -> 5;
        1 -> 3;
        1 -> 2;
        4 -> 4;
}
```

which means that the first edge to appear is 1->5 instead of the first defined 1->2. How can I force the order? I would like to see the nodes and edges in the order created.

Comment: did you solved this?